# Rails 4 - assert_select not working with element updated by javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, integration-testing

I have a span element that is blank by default and updated when the page is loaded by javascript. This works great - however assert_select seems only able to get the initial HTML - BEFORE the page is finished loading. Is this the expected behavior? What am I doing wrong?

span element in a scaffold generated _form.html.erb:

```
...
<span id="confirm_loaded"></span>
...
```

---- In a .js file in app/assets/javascripts:

```
$(function(){
  $("#confirm_loaded").html("test");
});
```

---- When I load the page -- the page is updated via javascript and all is well.

However, in an integration test - this line:

```
assert_select "span#confirm_loaded", {text: "test"}
```

fails with the error:

```
<test> expected but was
<>..
Expected 0 to be >= 1.
```

which appears to confirm that the test isn't seeing the updated HTML element set by javascript (perhaps it's running before the page is fully loaded?)

A quick change to the page, remove the javascript and hardcode the HTML:

```
...
<span id="confirm_loaded">test</span>
...
```

And now the test passes (the assert_select is able to get the value and we're golden).

Is assert_select only able to get the initial value of HTML tags? Why is the assert_select *not* getting values updated by javascript as the page loads?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please note, for the purposes of narrowing this down - I went ahead and removed the turbolinks gems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thinking through this a bit, it could simply be the case that the command line tests are getting the response from the server and offering it up for parsing / verification.

This would have two important aspects:

1. Scripts & client-side code would not be executed
2. Enter on to the scene - testing frameworks that offer up browser interfaces, etc - so that client-side code gets rendered

Seems like this is the case - but - I'll leave the question open in case I'm missing something.

Answer (score 6):

**Yes**, you said right in you question. **assert_select** selects elements and makes equality tests on **@response(@response.body)** object. That's the actual response returned form server, so at that time no javascript code has executed so you get span with empty text. As scripts runs in your browser.

Comment: I think we can only detect some things in the js output like: `assert_equals @item.count, @response.body.scan('item-id').count`

Comment: The response would have changed anyway